# Django ManyToMany join query

Tags: django

I'm sure this is really simple, but I can't for the life of me find any documentation explaining how to do this.

How do I get the results of a ManyToMany field inside a join as opposed to doing this:

```
{% for tag in article.tags.all %}
```

Which results in an extra query? What I'd like to do is fetch all related tags when I retrieve the initial article, so I could then do something like:

```
{% for tag in article.tags %}
```

Without the .all and the extra query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[django-batch-select](http://github.com/lilspikey/django-batch-select/) does just what you want and a bit more :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. `select_related()` is the usual way to follow joins in a single query, but it doesn't work with ManyToMany relations.

Comment: So a custom query is my only option? Does Python support grouping?